# How can I list all tables existent in a Database Link (Oracle)?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Basically I have a Database link (Oracle) called *mylink.domain*, in this link we can access foundation information like name of them members and other general information.

I would like to list all table's name in this link but i don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 32):

You can access the [`all_tables`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_2117.htm#REFRN20286) view through the dblink:

```
select owner, table_name
from all_tables@dblink
order by owner, table_name;
```

Comment: I tried this code before, but didn't show the linked tables.

Database Link: mylink.domain
One table in this link: foundation.members@mylink

if I run a "select * from foundation.member@mylink" all rows are fetched. when I ran your select this table doesn't appear.

Comment: @IgorAbreu , have you created the db link in the proper schema? 

please check the username and service name given while creating the db link

Comment: @IgorAbreu: what is the username that is used to connect to the other instance in the DBLink? You are prefixing the table name with a schema, so it seems the table is not in the schema of the DbLink's user. But if you have access to the table, it should show up in `all_table`. What happens if you use `where owner = 'FOUNDATION'` with my query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have a link and this link appoint to my production version in my production version a have a user called foundation, if I check in Sql Developer i can see all tables.

I dont understand why I cannot see using a select

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the content of ALL_TABLES dictionary view will list you all tables your user has access to. Generally, it is not always possible to get a list of tables you dont have permissions for - they just do not show up. If your user has the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY priviledge, you can select the content of DBA_TABLES, which will always list all tables existing in the database.

Answer (score 0):

select table_name from all_tables@dblinkname;

This shows all tables your linked user has access to.

[Where I got the answer from](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27297655/See-all-tables-within-an-oracle-dblink.html)

Comment: This is a reduced extract of an existing answer.