# Querying table names that belongs to another database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I would like to query all the table names that belongs to another database. I can query the contents of a table in another database using oracle links for example: `select * from owner.tablename@another_database;` but how do I select the owner name and table names of the tables in another database? Thank you.

Comment: Look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555790/how-can-i-list-all-tables-existent-in-a-database-link-oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT * FROM user_tables@another_database;